# House water supply "mystery branch" upstream from shutoff valve

Tags: plumbing, basement

I have a 1953 ranch with daylight basement. Pictured below is the point where (I believe) the water main enters the house horizontally (water meter is out in front lawn at ground level, aligned with this entrance). Upon entering, there is a T branch. Upwards pipe goes to a shutoff valve, while the downward branch disappears into the floor and is upstream of the shutoff. I can't figure out why this was done this way. It's possible I have it reversed and that supply comes out of the floor and then goes back out of the house at the T, again before the shut off valve. I am trying to track down the many possible causes of a damp floor in this area and would like to understand why this was done this way before going further. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I have called a plumber (I don't want to DIY myself into a bigger mess on this particular project) and will update once I get an answer.

[image: Main house water supply, coming in to T either from the floor or from midpoint]

[image]

[image: Edge of meter box, with house in distance showing hosebib - supply to this hosebib shown in image 4]

[image: Top of main line showing branch to hose bib with separate shutoff]

[image: Water meter]

[image: House-side outlet of water meter, angled into ground]

Comment: Where you are would probably affect the likely entrance point of the water supply (due to frost depth.) Though merely having an outside meter implies shallow or no frost depth. There may be an additional shutoff at the meter, though this is certainly an odd arrangement.

Comment: I'm in the Pacific NW USA, so I think "shallow or no" frostline is about right.

Comment: My vote is the water comes from below and the branch going through the wall feeds something else. Are there any out buildings or water spigots on that side  of the property ? or another pipe coming out of the floor in the basement somewhere ?

Comment: Could the valve be the shut-off for the house only? The line that Tees off could be to supply the outside faucets. If this a pier-and beam, have you looked under the house to see if there is a cutoff there for the line going through the foundation?

Comment: There is a water spigot near there on front of house but it is fed by a branch downstream of the shutoff. Interestingly, there are two spigots on the back of the house that have been disconnected (capped off inside the wall from what I can tell from the one I can access) and I am starting to wonder if it is a feeder line for those. There is one additional hosebib on the house that looks newer and is affected by the main shutoff. There are no additional outbuildings.

Comment: @JimStewart Not pier and beam - full concrete foundation walls in basement. Can't see what's happening on other side of wall. That horizontal branch is ~4 feet underground on other side of that wall.

Comment: OK I misunderstood, this is *inside* the basement, right? The incoming line is horizontal into the Tee and the line goes up to the valve and down under the floor.  I am surprised there is no shutoff valve on the down leg!

Comment: Can you add a photo of the meter from the front lawn? And of the device that is cut off at the top of the original photo?

Comment: @DougDeden new images added. The device above (downstream from) the shutoff is I think a pressure regulator. A pic shows the top of the supply line, where a hose bib supply branches off to the right. This hose bib can be seen on the exterior of the house in another shot, about in line with the meter box.

Comment: Something else I did yesterday - ran water in a nearby sink while trying to listen to the pipes to see if I could hear flow. This might not be of much use as I can imagine the sound resonating through any connected pipe. I heard the sound of flow through the pipe emerging from the floor and then I put my ear to the concrete below, and heard flow there too. To be honest, not sure if this tells me anything. I could not get my ear close to the horizontal T branch and don't have a stethoscope. But the more I write, this seems like useless information... :)

Comment: *I am starting to wonder if it is a feeder line for those* That's my guess. My house is set up exactly that way - there's a tee upstream of the main shutoff right after the supply line enters the basement, that tee feeds two hose spigots on the opposite side of the house, which each have their own shutoffs.

Answer (score 2):

And the answer is.... water line comes in horizontally. BUT, a shocking discovery made by my plumber while sorting this out. Somebody else in the past had the same idea as me and started to remove the downpipe, then abandoned the effort. They made a horizontal cut into the pipe below the T, from behind. It was not easily viewable from the front. I put a feeler gauge into the cut slot and it appears to be DEEPER than the pipe wall thickness. Basically, it's just rust and gunk that has kept the water from exploding out of that slot. I've encountered my fair share of home improvement crime scenes over the years, but this one is right up there... a glob of rust away from disaster.

[image: Finished Job]
[image: Pipe cut by previous jacka** of all trades]

Comment: +1 for "home improvement crime scenes." So, it's still a mystery as to what the down leg is/was for?

Comment: @TimNevins, yes, have not formally solved the downleg question, although I have high confidence it's a run to the two decommissioned hose bibs on the back of the house. If I get motivated (and find a long piece of wire) I might do a conductivity test between the now disconnected down leg and the capped off supply to the hosebib I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

Does the property have any underground irrigation system -- sprinklers for a lawn, for instance? If so, is that system fed with potable water?

It might be that the supply from the meter rises from the floor and the branch going through the wall supplies the irrigation system. One would hope for a shutoff valve in that branch. Since no valve is visible on the branch going through the wall, maybe there's also a stop-and-waste valve buried nearby outdoors. The only sign visible on the surface of the ground might be a 3 or 4 inch diameter pipe going straight down, hopefully with a lid to keep out debris.

Comment: Condensation for one .The old pipes are breaking down. Would be my guess. For water stains. and is the floor sealed good.

Comment: No sprinkler or irrigation system that I know of. No sign of any valve or control box outside the house in this area. It's a fairly straight shot from the meter box in the lawn to the house and were I betting, I'd put money on the middle horizontal line being the main. Might do some excavation in the flower bed in front of the house to see if I can find the line or any buried shutoff.

Comment: @RobertMoody floor is unsealed - this is actually the genesis of this whole effort. I cleaned out this room and scrubbed floor in order to prep for epoxy paint. The area in question was wet before (in appearance - no puddling) but we had to do some cat cleanup and I assumed it was that. Now, I've scrubbed, squeegeed and shopvac'd the whole area and had a fan overnight. Most of the rest of the room is dry now except for this area, which still looks damp. Definitely suspecting breakdown of underground water pipe.

Comment: Your lucky you even get water out of those old pipes. The rust one day may break off and no water at all.Sock away and some day add new line.

Comment: Sock away is a term my dad used to save your penny for a rainy day.

Answer (score 0):

You have a main shut off . And tee fitting after that . Steel pipe is old or no good. and you may have a leak. Because in slab. disconnect run new pipes over head to house done.